# Calculate $\iint_S \sin(x+y)dxdy$

Tags: integration

Let S be the region bounded by the lines $y=x, x+y = \frac{\pi}{2}, y=0$ and calculate the double integral

$$\iint_S \sin(x+y)dxdy$$

I have sketched the region and get the following:
[image]

I'm unsure as to whether I integrate with respect to the lower triangle, or the top left triangle.

I have for the integral bounds the following when integrating from bottom:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{y}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-y}\sin(x+y)dxdy$$

Was this the correct region to integrate, otherwise - how do I tell?

Comment: Is top left triangle bounded by $y=0$?

Comment: $y$ is from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $S$.

Comment: $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$ can be found from $x=y=\frac{\pi}{2}-y$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu ah yes! thanks for pointing that out it's now corrected my understanding on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, per the symmetry of the four triangle regions
$$\iint_S \sin(x+y)\>dxdy
=\frac14 \int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \sin(x+y)\>dxdy=\frac12$$